Inverse image of a bounded set by a differentiable map from a normed vector space to itself
I am working through the following problem. I've already shown that the function is injective by generalizing Rolle's theorem for normed spaces. However, I am unsure how to prove the second claim.

Let $E$ be a normed vector space and $f\colon E\to E$ differentiable. Suppose that there exists $k \in(0,1)$ such that $\Vert D_x f - \text{Id}_E \Vert _{\mathcal{L}(E)} \leq k$ for all $x \in E$.
Prove that $f$ is injective and that the inverse image of a bounded set is bounded.

Allegedly, the mean value inequality (for normed spaces) has to be used, which I cite here for reference:

Let $E$ and $F$ be normed vector spaces, $O$ an open subset of $E$ and $f: O \longrightarrow F$ differentiable on $O$. If  $a + t(b-a) \in O$ for all $t\in [0,1]$, then
$$
\|f(b)-f(a)\|_F \leq \sup _{x \in(a, b)}\left|D_x f \right|_{\mathcal{L}(E, F)}\|b-a\|_E .
$$

Any help would be appreciated.

You can use that formulation of the mean value inequality to show that
\begin{equation}
\|(f(x) - x) - (f(y) - y) \|_{E} \leq k\|x - y\|_{E}
\end{equation}
for all $x,y\in E$. As a consequence, if $x,y\in E$, then
\begin{align*}
\|f(x) - f(y)\|_{E} &= \|(x-y) + [(f(x) - x ) - (f(y) - y)]\|_{E} \\
&\geq \|x - y\|_{E} - \|(f(x) - x) - (f(y) - y)\|_{E} \\
&\geq \|x - y\|_{E} - k\|x - y\|_{E} \\
&= (1-k) \|x - y\|_{E}.
\end{align*}
This inequality can be used to show that $f$ is injective and that the inverse image of a bounded set under $f$ is again a bounded set. More specifically, it can be used to show that $f^{-1}(B_{E}(f(x_{0}), r) ) \subseteq B_{E}(x_{0}, (1-k)^{-1}r)$ when $x_{0}\in E$ and $r>0$, where $B_{E}(y, s) = \{x\in E : \|x - y\|_{E} < s \}$ for $y\in E$ and $s>0$.
